# How to become a good mathematician?

Tags: soft-question, big-list

[HOW to BECOME a GOOD  THEORETICAL PHYSICIST by Gerard 't Hooft (Nobel Prize Winner)](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/theorist.html)

Is there similar "How to become a good mathematician by **__**"?

*Humble Suggestion : Why not build it here?*

Comment: I don't think I have added the right tags. Please,help!

Comment: I don't think that this is an appropriate question for this site as it is not focussed on an answerable question about research-level mathematics.

Comment: It is commonly said that there are theory-builders (à la Grothendieck, say) and problem-solvers (à la Erdös). I think it is better to start one's career with problem solving and move to theory building than the other way around. Work on hard problems, so that any progress you make is meaningful. If you have some success, you might gain the background for successful theory-building based on (as Ernst Straus quoted another mathematician) "the great metatheorems...in the back of [one's] mind".

Comment: My initial response to this question was also slightly negative. But upon inspection, that page by 't Hooft turns out to be rather interesting, even though certain sentiments are expressed a bit too strongly for my taste. The question of designing a similar guide to mathematics is not entirely uninteresting either. Being unable to call myself a 'good' mathematician, I don't think I'll attempt it myself.

Comment: Andrew -- did you take a look at 't Hooft's page? He doesn't give any nonsense advice on doing good physics and repeating it but instead gives a rather detailed curriculum together with a list of books to read with indications on pros and cons of any particular book. I think it may be interesting to try and do the same for mathematics. Chances are there will be less agreement among mathematicians on what exactly goes into such curriculum than among the physicists, and there will be several alternative versions, but in my opinion this would make sense nonetheless.

Comment: Closed, c.f. Andrew's comment.

Comment: And the Powers-That-Be at the top slices the roots off another potentially good posting.Sigh.

Comment: I did not say that I thought it was not an interesting question (I did not say that I did, either) but that it is not appropriate _here_.  If anyone wishes to take me up on it further, start a thread on meta.

Comment: Define `good mathematician'. 

Comment: Someone once told me that good mathematicians are those who do good mathematics and good mathematics is something that good mathematcians do.

Answer (score 4):

While you are young, do your best to find out the most important mathematical subjects you may be capable of learning reasonably well, and learn them, and as many of them as possible.

Comment: The way I would put this is: Learn everything you can, whether you think you're good or interested at it, but stay focused on where your interests and strengths lie. I know that this is contradictory, but I don't know of any logically consistent advice that I can offer. 

Answer (score 2):

There is: How to Solve it, by George Polya (reprinted by Princeton University Press, 2004).

Answer (score 0):

Do good maths. Repeat.

Comment: Gee,how insightful,Tom. I'm sure that'll be incredibly helpful to aspiring undergraduates.

Comment: http://www.ibras.dk/montypython/episode28.htm#3